# Is it possible to create links between two perforce repositories?

Tags: linux, repository, perforce, symlink, ln

Is it possible to create a link between two perforce repositories, kind of like symbolic links in linux.

Example:
//depot/mydir/A@ -> //depot/mydir/B/

So when you try to sync //depot/mydir/A, you will sync //depot/mydir/B/...
Or integrate, or so on.

I am not sure if such thing is possible. I will really appreciate some input on this matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remote depots might be what you're looking for:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Using-Remote-Depots

A remote depot allows you to map part of the namespace of one server into a top-level depot in another server.  You might create a remote depot called "B" on your server that maps to "//depot/mydir/B" on the remote server; then when you sync //B/... you're actually syncing //depot/mydir/B/... from the other server.